# How do I get a Sencha controller to respond to a swipe event in a view?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a dataview that I would like to detect a swipe on. It'd be great if I could listen for that in the controller, but as far as I understand I can't do that. My testing bears this out. So instead I need to listen in the view for the event. Currently I'm doing that in the initialize method of my data view like so:

```
initialize: function() {
    var el = Ext.get("list");
    el.on('swipe', function(event) {
      alert(event.direction);
    });
}
```

So a couple of things:

- Is my understanding correct, that I have to listen for DOM events like this in the view?
- Is this the best way to set the swipe listener on the dataview? I couldn't seem to make it work through the config object.
- How do I then let my controller know about the swipe? It will need to manipulate the view when the swipe happens (like change the view size). What are the best practices in this area?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to put the events for a component inside the controller. So, first create a *ref* for that dataview in your controller.

```
refs : {
   listView : 'list' //Or a selector to get the reference
},
control : {
   listView : {
       // Dataview has an "itemswipe" event - not "swipe" event
       itemswipe : function(dataview, index, target, record){
           //Do here what you want 
       }
   }
}
```

This should work (not tested).

Comment: Argh, I tried something like that in my tests, but somehow missed the itemswipe event. Thanks, works.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after, its the same idea just changing the scope to the controller:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.myListControler', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {

        refs: {
            list: { selector: 'myList', autoCreate: true, xtype: 'myList' }
        }

    },

    init: function () {

    },

    launch: function () {

         this.getList().on('swipe', this.onSwipe);

    },

    onSwipe: function (event) {
         console.log(event.direction);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for getting the swipe event from the controller like requested. I'm going with Swar's solution, but thanks for the direction.